# 'Permission Denied' when trying to make Jquery $.ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function populateGroups(){
var p =1;
var groupNames = new Array();
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
    url: "http://okcmonprd103/iMon/findgroups.pl",
    dataType: "text/xml",
    success: function parseGroupNames(xml){

            $(xml).find('group').each(function(){
                    groupNames[p] = $(this).find('name').text();
                    p++;
            });
            groupNames.sort(arraySort);
            for(p=0;p<groupNames.length-1;p++){
                $('#Groups').append('<option value="'+p+1+'">'+groupNames[p]+'</option>');
                $('#dutyGroups').append('<option value="'+p+'">'+groupNames[p]+'</option>');
                }
    }
});
```

}

I send this ajax call to a server on our network that runs a Perl script that returns XML data. This works fine on my machine in IE8, and in my Windows 7 Gadget (which is what this is mainly for) but whenever other people in the company try to use it, they get the "Permission Denied" error. Do I need to set up a proxy page in order to make this work?

It does work on my machine, I just don't see how other people on the same network wouldn't be able to use this...

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't gotten an answer yet. This is an extremely frequent question here: you cannot make AJAX requests to a URL with a different protocol/hostname/port than that of the page where the script is running. It works from your local machine because the browser drops the restriction in that case. It's called the "same origin policy" and it's written up in many places.

Comment: I read that initially as well that he was running it on his own machine.  After a re-read, it sounds like it is on a server that he can access with his machine but no one else can.

Comment: But it also works on two other co-workers computers in my building... I just don't see what the difference is between them and the other guy down the hall from me where it's not working

Comment: They all have access to the server because I can send them the URL for the Perl script on the server and the browser shows the returned XML from a SOAP request

Comment: Your URL just mentions a hostname without any domain name.  Perhaps other machines on your network assume a different default domain.

Comment: Another possibility is that the security settings for the non-working machines differ from those on the working machines.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well. My IE settings for local intranet could be more lax than the others. The issue is that These ajax requests aren't running in my Windows Gadget and I don't know how to change those settings

Comment: I set my IE settings for local intranet all the way up to HIGH and enabled protected mode and it still worked...

Comment: Try running like a trace route (tracert) type command from the user for whom the request is not working. Pointy might be right in the domain issue, and it would be good to see what each computer is trying to access.

Comment: Just checked the tracert... his machine takes the same exact steps as mine to connect to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it was a Windows 7 issue. When you right clicked on the HTML file name, under security, it would say something like "this file is blocked because it came from another computer"

All you had to do was press the "Unblock" button and all of a sudden it worked.